# Is there a special way to layout WKWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am having an issue with WKWebView I init like this

```
    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        configuration.applicationNameForUserAgent = "Browser"
        configuration.ignoresViewportScaleLimits = true
        configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        configuration.allowsAirPlayForMediaPlayback = true
        configuration.allowsPictureInPictureMediaPlayback = true
        configuration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = WKAudiovisualMediaTypes.audio
        configuration.selectionGranularity = WKSelectionGranularity.character
        configuration.dataDetectorTypes = WKDataDetectorTypes.link
    let webview = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)
        webview.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        webview.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        webview.uiDelegate = self
        webview.navigationDelegate = self
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webview.load(request)
        self.view = webview
```

everytime I enter a search box on a website for example "Google" I get this log in the debugger... I can't seem to understand why it is throwing constraint issues while I did not set any... and this view is contained in `UINavigationController` that has a `UIToolbar`

[image: Picture 1/2]
[image: Picture 2/2]

Screenshot of Storyboard.

[image: Container View]

Comment: @Miteshjadav WKWebview's support in Storyboard for if your deployment target is iOS 11.0. Otherwise, you can't set WKWebview in the storyboard. You have to set frame or constraint programmatically.

Comment: @Miteshjadav this didn't the trick mate.